# Image via uri not being displayed

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, jsx

I have the following React Native component where I'm trying to display some text and an image in an Android emulator.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class ListItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> "Some text" </Text>
                <Image
                  source={{uri: "https://facebookbrand.com/wp-content/themes/fb-branding/prj-fb-branding/assets/images/fb-art.png"}}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

The text is displayed correctly but the image is not shown. The `uri` for the image is correct.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: You need to give `{width, height}` for external images. For more information you can check [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#network-images)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike with static resources, for network resources, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image.

```
// GOOD
<Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
       style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />

// BAD
<Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} />
```

For more information about Image resources check the official documentation:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#network-images